# Undefined Reference to yylval in lex program

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

I am working on Lex and Yacc program but I am getting error as :

> /tmp/ccTP9YY1.o: In function `yylex':
>   lex.yy.c:(.text+0x289): undefined reference to`yylval'
>   lex.yy.c:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to `yylval'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have searched a lot on Internet like stackoverflow and other sites but none of them seems to capable of solving my problem. I might be implementing those suggestions incorrectly. Can anyone please suggest me anything about this ?
Thanks in advance.

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
void yyerror(char *); 
%}
%%
[a-z]  {
      yylval = *yytext - 'a';
      return VARIABLE;
       }
[0-9]+ {
      yylval = atoi(yytext);
      return INTEGER;
   }
[-+()=/*\n] { return *yytext; }
[ \t]        ;
.  {  yyerror("invalid character");   }

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int yywrap(void) {
   return 1;
}
```

Commands used :

```
rohit@rohit-HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:~$ lex echo.l
rohit@rohit-HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:~$ yacc -d yaccCalc.y 
rohit@rohit-HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC:~$ gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.h -ll
/tmp/ccTP9YY1.o: In function `yylex':
lex.yy.c:(.text+0x289): undefined reference to `yylval'
lex.yy.c:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to `yylval'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Yacc file :

```
%token INTEGER VARIABLE
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%{
   void yyerror(char *);
   int yylex(void);
   int sym[26];
%}

%%

program:
    program statement '\n'
    | 
    ;

statement:
    expr                      { printf("%d\n", $1); }
    | VARIABLE '=' expr       { sym[$1] = $3; }
    ;

expr:
    INTEGER
    | VARIABLE                { $$ = sym[$1]; }
    | expr '+' expr           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr '-' expr           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | expr '*' expr           { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expr '/' expr           { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | '(' expr ')'            { $$ = $2; }
    ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
   yyparse();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to link the scanner with the parser (because `yylval` is defined in the parser). I'm certain that that is what the other answers say, but it is not possible to tell what error you made in attempting to accomplish it unless you reveal the precise commands you used to compile and link your project.

Comment: sorry I did'nt put it. Now I've edited with commands and yacc file

Comment: Change `y.tab.h` to `y.tab.c` in the `gcc` command. Compiling a header file doesn't do what you think it does, and it wouldn't help even if it did because the definition of `yylval` is not in the header file, only the declaration. (You already #include the header file generated in `lex.yy.c`, so `yylval` is declared. The linker error is because it is never defined.)

Answer (score 2):

Two files are generated by Yacc (and Bison), namely `y.tab.h` and `y.tab.c` assuming you do not override the output file with option `-o`.  Include `y.tab.h` in your source code and compile `y.tab.c`. So perhaps you made a typo when trying to compile:

```
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll
-------------------^-------- compile y.tab.c, not y.tab.h
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: Done. I should have explained this.

Answer (score 2):

You should compile the `.c` file, not the `.h` file. Below is the command you need to compile your lex and yacc program:

```
1. yacc -d yaccCalc.y
2. lex echo.l
3. cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll -ly
```